# I can't click on anything in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't click on anything in Minecraft. I am not in adventure mode, I can place blocks and torches and stuff, but I can't break anything or use any items. When I go to the menu, I can't click and save the game either. I was looking at my coordinates when I accidently hit escape and I was confused and then I hit escape again and that it when I couldn't hit or break blocks or anything. Then I tried doing it again to see if it would fix the problem, but it didn't. If anyone can help or send advice, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it still happen when you restart the game

Comment: I haven't done that. I don't know how. I don't think it will let me.

Comment: you are going to need to restart it anyway, also can you click anything else (not minecraft) if not then it is a hardware issue

Comment: I have the game paused right now, and I minimized the page so I could look for solutions, I seriously have no idea how this happened. How do I restart it anyway?

Comment: just close the minecraft window (it will shut down cleanly) and then start it up again

Comment: Oh my goodness, I think it worked. Thanks. I kind of feel stupid though, by not thinking about it before.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think you should put that as an answer so that Hayler could accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -4):

I think you might have a polemic but just go to the launcher (minecraft) and hit profile then duplicate your own profile then launch that